# How can I get n largest lists from a list of lists in python

Tags: python

I am using heapq  to get nlargest elements from list of lists. The program I wrote is below.

```
import csv
import heapq
f = open("E:/output.csv","r")
read = csv.reader(f)

allrows = [row for row in read]

for i in xrange(0,2):
     print allrows[i]

allrows.sort(key=lambda x: x[2]) #this is working properly
it=heapq.nlargest(20,enumerate(allrows),key=lambda x:x[2]) #error
```

I just want the top 20 elements. So Instead of sorting I thought of using a heap. The error I am getting is,

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\eclipse_progs\DaDv\IMDB\Assignment1.py", line 42, in <module>
  it=heapq.nlargest(2,enumerate(allrows),key=lambda x:x[2])
File "C:\Python27\lib\heapq.py", line 470, in nlargest
  result = _nlargest(n, it)
File "D:\eclipse_progs\DaDv\IMDB\Assignment1.py", line 42, in <lambda>
  it=heapq.nlargest(2,enumerate(allrows),key=lambda x:x[2])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Can I know why I am getting the error and how to resolve it. Is there any property of using heapq I am missing.

Comment: whats the length of your rows ? are those same ?

Comment: Yes they are size 4. All of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enumerate()` returns an iterable over 2-tuples. Thus accessing `x[2]` in your second example is always going to be out of range (the only valid indices are 0 and 1).

To make the second example equivalent to the first, you should be passing `allrows` directly instead of using `enumerate()`:

```
it = heapq.nlargest(20, allrows, key=lambda x:x[2])
```

If you need to preserve the original indices, `enumerate()` is the way to go. However, you also need an additional level of indirection in the key function:

```
it = heapq.nlargest(20, enumerate(allrows), key=lambda x:x[1][2]) 
                        ^^^^^^^^^                         ^^^
```

Comment: I get it now. Th enumerator returns a tuple. so x[1][2]. I wanted the indices as well so I was using enumerate.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks NPE for lighting the problem , As an alternative answer you can concatenate all of your rows with `itertools.chain()` and get top 20 element with sorting , that have more performance than `heapq` :

```
from itertools import chain

sorted(chain(*allrows))[-20:]
```

The `nlargest()` and `nsmallest()` functions are most appropriate if you are trying to
find a relatively small number of items. If you are simply trying to find the single smallest
or largest item `(N=1)`, it is faster to use `min()` and `max()` . Similarly, if N is about the
same size as the collection itself, it is usually faster to sort it first and take a slice (i.e.,
use `sorted(items)[:N]` or `sorted(items)[-N:]` ).

Comment: It would be nice to see some benchmarks to back up the performance claims (these things are often full of surprises).

Comment: @kasra OP is not asking the solution how to get top 20 elements, he is asking for the error that he is getting.

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay yes, even though this was not my qsn. I did not knew about this till now. So thank you Kasara.

Comment: @NPE yep , its possible but i say what that have been benchmarked before ! implementation of `nlargest()` and `nsmallest()` is adaptive in how it operates and will
carry out some of these optimizations on your behalf.

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay when NPE describe the problem correctly what i must say ? ;)